# Link absolute URIs correctly when loading pages locally

Tags: html, url

When developing pages, I like to load them in my browser locally to see how they look rather than have to deploy them to the server every time. I'm using Lift and server deployment takes a few seconds, and just running Lift puts a heavy strain on my old laptop. The problem is absolute paths e.g. */css/main.css*, while correct on the server, will cause the browser to search from the root filesystem e.g. *file:///css/main.css* when I open the page locally.

Is there a technique to be able to work with absolute paths, yet somehow trick the browser into using a different base to calculate the paths from when loading the pages locally? A browser plug-in perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to make your browser run a small webserver: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/browser-server/

Comment: Ah-ha, of course! I think I'll just run a standalone but lightweight web server. Thanks!